# Intermediate Value Theorem question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

The temperature $T(x)$ at each point $x$ on the surface of Mars (a sphere) is a continuous function. Show that there is a point $x$ on the surface such that $T(x)=T(-x)$

(Hint: Represent the surface of Mars as $\{x\in{\mathbb{R}^3}:||x||=1\}$.)

Consider the function $f(x)=T(x)-T(-x)$

---

So.....

I consider an unit sphere is locating at the origin of a $xyz$-plane.

As $||x||=1$, I can say with $radius = 1 = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

To find there is a point $T(x)=T(-x)$, we use the formula $f(x)=T(x)-T(-x)$ and show somehow $f(x)$ will equal to $0$ ???

It will be a point in the upper hemisphere and another point with the exactly opposite vector (if using $ijk$ plane) on the lower hemisphere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Pick some point $x$. If you are lucky, $f(x) = 0$, but probably this does not occur. In the other case, what can you say about the relation between $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$? Now connect $x$ and $-x$ using a path along the sphere...

Answer (score 1):

If f(x)=T(x)−T(−x) is zero, we are done. Assume there does not exist an x that makes f(x) zero. Then f(x)>0 or <0 for all x. If say f(x)>0 is never satisfied, then replacing x by -x we get a contradiction. Similarly if f(x)<0 never holds. So there must be points for which f(x)>0 and points for which f(x)<0. The intermediate value theorem then implies there must exist a point y at which f(y)=0 (contradiction).